# Customized Devise sessions controller doesn't work as expected

Tags: session, devise, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, customization

I customized some of the Devise's controllers following offical instruction :

- config/routes.rb has been modified with :

  devise_for :admin_utilisateurs, :controllers => {:registrations => 'admin_utilisateurs/registrations', :sessions => 'admin_utilisateurs/sessions'}
- Views have been generated and moved from app/view/devise/ to
  /app/view/admin_utilisateurs/

  I as well customized the model and migration for the admin_utilisateurs in order to have an 'active' column. So that the administrator may manually deactivate the account.

**Basically, what I want is that a user should not be able to sign_in if its admin_utilisateur.active attribut is false.**

This lead me to the following modification :

```
class AdminUtilisateurs::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # Surcharge of 'create' method in Devise::SessionsController
  # Example ressource : http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/10
  def create

    @admin_utilisateur = AdminUtilisateur.find_by_email(params[:email])

    if @admin_utilisateur.present? && @admin_utilisateur.active
      super

    else
      flash.now[:alert] = t('devise.failure.desactive')
      render :new and return

    end
  end
end
```

What is happening is that Rails goes to the correct customized 'create' method of app/controllers/admin_utilisateurs/sessions_controller.rb

If the user is not "activated" by the admin (admin_utilisateur.active = false) then I got the correct FLASH message, but RAILS authenticate it though !
So the user is still able to access all the ressources, even those guarded by the "before_filter :authenticate_admin_utilisateur!" instruction in their respective controller.

It looks like Rails si still somehow authenticating, though the "create" method is not coded to do so.

Any help is welcome!
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the only explanation I see is about this **prepend_before_filter** call at the top of the devise controller :

```
prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create
```

RDoc says : *Tell warden that params authentication is allowed for that specific page.*

I don't understand how warden works either.

Anyway !

I solved my problem with a different solution given by the wiki : [Require admin to activate account before sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in)

So I rolled back my migration. I modified ii in order that the column :desactive became :approved. I migrate. I modified my model app/models/admin_utilisateur.rb with the following :

```
def active_for_authentication? 
  super && approved? 
end 

def inactive_message 
  approved?  ? super : :not_approved 
end
```

I added the needed keys to my config/locales/fr.yml

And it works great !!! Why is it always so difficult to make it easy, and easy to make it difficult ;-)